# Why am I not able to assign boolean variable inside Observable?

Tags: angular, html, typescript, observable, angular7

I am trying to hide one of div element once after getting data from Service, the HTML Code you can Find Below

```
<progressbar
                *ngIf="isLoadingBootStockData"
                [value]="100"
                type="default">
</progressbar>
```

Initially I am assigning variable `isLoadingBootStockData` to false and assigning back to true once i get all the data from service 
So the typeScript code looks like this:

```
return this.cseStockService
    .getBootStockMaterials()
      .pipe(
         map((materialStock) => {
         this.isLoadingBootStockData = false;
const MaterialList = this.cseStockService.createCseStockMaterialModels(
                                materialStock,
                                this.model.notification,
                                this.model.listMaterial,
                                CSE_STOCK.BOOT_STOCK
                            );
}).subscribe()
```

So in above code 5th Line , I will get data from Service and  I am assigning variable to `this.isLoadingBootStockData = false;`
So that the html div `<progressBar>...</progressBar>` get Hides

However, here the problem, the variable is not getting assign to false. Since i am using in observable , is it not possible ?

If not, how can I do it ? I want to make that variable false once after loading data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observable will execute once you subscribe it. You have to place a following line in subscribe method as

```
    return this.cseStockService
        .getBootStockMaterials()
          .pipe(
             map((materialStock) => {

    const MaterialList = this.cseStockService.createCseStockMaterialModels(
                                    materialStock,
                                    this.model.notification,
                                    this.model.listMaterial,
                                    CSE_STOCK.BOOT_STOCK
                                );
    }).subscribe((res:any)=>{
       this.isLoadingBootStockData = false;
    });
```

Comment: No.. its not working.. i think i have problem with binding. its not at all binding in HTML .. i have added `{{isLoadingBootStockData}}` in HTML , it is returning true instead of false.